# Querying File Directly vs Querying Data Frame after reading the File

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Method 1:
Querying a parquet file directly as :

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT columns FROM parquet.`sample.parquet`")
```

and

Method 2:
Querying the Dataframe after reading a parquet file as :

```
df = spark.read.parquet(path_to_parquet_file)
df.select(columns)
```

and

Method 3:
Querying a Temporary View as :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT columns FROM sample")
```

1. Behind the scene, are all 3 essentially executed the same way ?
2. In Method 1, does the parquet get converted into dataframe / dataset
   before query execution ?
3. Which of the 3 methods are efficient and why ? (if they are
   different)
4. Is there a specific use case for these methods ? (if they are
   different)

Thank You !

Comment: There is a difference between method 2 & the other two methods, as you have described in your question. Method 2 involves a `select` operation on some columns (a projection operation) which the other two do not have. This makes its execution markedly different from the other two. Is this intentional?

Comment: No. It wasn't intentional. Intent is to understand the difference between the 3 methods given that it gives the same end result. I have edited the question to avoid ambiguity, based on your comments. Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Yes. The 3 ways you have illustrated of querying a Parquet file using Spark are executed in the same way.

**Long Answer**

The reason why this is so is a combination of two features of Spark: [lazy evaluation](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/) & [query optimization](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html).

As a developer, you could split the Spark operations into multiple steps (as you have done in method 2). Internally, Spark (lazily) evaluates the operations in conjunction and applies optimizations on it. In this case, Spark could optimize the operations by column pruning (basically, it will not read the entire parquet data into memory; only the specific columns you have requested.)

The 3rd method of creating a temporary view is just about naming the data you have read, so that you can reference in further operations. It does not change how it is computed in the first place.

For more information on optimizations performed by Spark in reading Parquet, refer this [in-depth article](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-06-diving-spark-and-parquet-workloads-example).

**NOTE:**
As I have mentioned in a comment to the question, you have selected specific columns in method 2; while the other two reads the entire data. Since, these are essentially different operations, there will be difference in execution. The above answer assumes similar operations are been performed in each of the three methods (either reading complete data or some specific columns from the file).

Comment: Yes, assumed rightly. Edited the question based on your comments. Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to evaluate which '3' of them is best for same objective, There is no difference in between those. `physical plan` tell's your ask - 'Behind the scene?'.

Method 1:

```
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT CallNumber,CallFinalDisposition FROM parquet.`/tmp/ParquetA`").show()

== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- *(1) Project [cast(CallNumber#2988 as string) AS CallNumber#3026, CallFinalDisposition#2992]
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [CallNumber#2988,CallFinalDisposition#2992] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/tmp/ParquetA], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CallNumber:int,CallFinalDisposition:string>
```

Method 2:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/tmp/ParquetA')
df.select("CallNumber","CallFinalDisposition").show()

== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- *(1) Project [cast(CallNumber#3100 as string) AS CallNumber#3172, CallFinalDisposition#3104]
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [CallNumber#3100,CallFinalDisposition#3104] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/tmp/ParquetA], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CallNumber:int,CallFinalDisposition:string>
```

Method 3:

```
tempDF = spark.read.parquet('/tmp/ParquetA/')
tempDF.createOrReplaceTempView("temptable");
tiny = spark.sql("SELECT CallNumber,CallFinalDisposition FROM temptable").show()

== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- *(1) Project [cast(CallNumber#2910 as string) AS CallNumber#2982, CallFinalDisposition#2914]
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [CallNumber#2910,CallFinalDisposition#2914] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/tmp/ParquetA], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CallNumber:int,CallFinalDisposition:string>
```